# String manupulation in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a code in which the variable `strp` contains `string`

```
strp = "HELLO WORLD . I AM NEW TO PYTHON"
```

I want to get output as

`HELLO WORLD` only when `print strp`

What string manipulation operation should be performed to achieve this?

I am using python 2.7

Comment: `print strp` will just print the contents of `strp`. You just need to change `strp` to have the contents that you want to print.

Comment: What string operations come to mind when you only want part of a string? Try to research those and experiment around yourself, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
print strp.split('.')[0]
```

`split` on the punctuation and get the first item

Answer (score 1):

Using `split`:

```
strp.split(' . ')[0]
Out[51]: 'HELLO WORLD'
```

Directly indexing:

```
strp[:11]
Out[52]: 'HELLO WORLD'
```

Or using `re`:

```
import re
re.split('[.\s]\s*', strp)
Out[55]: ['HELLO', 'WORLD', '', 'I', 'AM', 'NEW', 'TO', 'PYTHON']
' '.join(re.split('\s*[.\s]\s*', strp)[0:2])
Out[58]: 'HELLO WORLD'
```

Answer (score 1):

First you locate `.` in `strp` and then print the substring of `strp` before it:

```
strp = "HELLO WORLD . I AM NEW TO PYTHON"

period_location = strp.find(".")
print(strp[:period_location])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't because print strp will print the contents of strp.  You can print just part of the variable, for example, using

```
print strp[0:11]
```